# Get data from API in Google Apps Script, how to?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

im trying to access the calendar resources data in the Google Apps domain.

I have this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/example.com/';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);

}
```

But i need to authorize.

"Request failed for https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/example.com/ returned code 401. Authorization required "

Does someone know how i Authorize? I tried to add the advances services and Calendar API, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) in Google Apps Script. It allows you to interact with Calendar Objects and Events without worrying for oAuth.

e.g to Fetch Events in Calendar

```
function fetchEVents() {
  var d1 = new Date("4/26/2013");
  var d2 = new Date("4/26/2014");
  var events = CalendarApp.openByName("myCalendarName").getEvents(d1, d2);

  if (events.length > 0) { // Log the time of first event
    Logger.log(events[0].getStartTime() + " : " + events[0].getEndTime());
  }
}
```

For more details, you may refer to the following resources.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sites_tutorial#section2